# JQuery Datepicker doesn't change input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a Jquery UI Datepicker addon as DateTimePicker http://jsfiddle.net/j5rkbnrt/1/

```
<input id="deliveryTime" name="deliveryTime" type="text" value="08/05/2015 10:00">

 $('#deliveryTime').datetimepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
 });
```

The DateTimePicker is associated to the input field.
When I select the date the value of the input field is not changed.
So when I submit the form containing this input I always get the default value.

I had a look at the default jquery datepicker and that also doesn't change the value of the input. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

What am I missing here?

Comment: You jsfiddle example is working fine in firefox. which browser you are testing on??

Comment: Works fine on chrome too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tkay/j5rkbnrt/2/ works fine here.

Comment: working fine in firefox and chrome. Are you using IE7 or less?

Comment: I'm on Chrome and it doesn't work. Version 39.0.2171.99 OSVersion Linux: 3.13.0-35-generic.
I've tried on Firefox 32.0 and there it's working fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are confusing the inline `value` **attribute** with the **actual value that the input field contains**.

By the attribute value, I mean the following:

```
<input id="deliveryTime" name="deliveryTime" type="text" value="08/05/2015 10:00">
```

The value **attribute** is `value="08/05/2015 10:00"`. The value could be whatever date you picked that is entered into the input field.

So even if the attribute is `value="08/05/2015 10:00"`, the input's actual value, meaning whatever text is in the input field, is the real value.

When you do enter a new value into your input and then use `$('#deliveryTime').val()` you will see that your new value is the actual value of the text inside the input field.

If you are keen on changing the **attribute** of your input field, which I find kind of ambiguous since `val()` already returns that value, then you need to do the following:

```
$('#deliveryTime').change(function(){
    $(this).attr('value', $('#deliveryTime').val());
});
```

So "On each change of the deliveryTime, set the `value` attribute to the input value". [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/j5rkbnrt/8/)

As I said, this is ambiguous. I would recommend just using `$('#deliveryTime').val()` to fulfill the same purpose.

Comment: Hi Rizky thanks for clarifying this. I understand I should not look for changes at the actual attribute value. The problem is that my Chrome version doesn't actually send the correct value when I submit the form. It works on Firefox though.
The value sent is still the old one. Even though the console.log is logging the correct value changes

Comment: You're welcome. That is strange, so even if you use `$('#deliveryTime').val()` in your developer console of Chrome, you don't get a value?

Comment: @spike07 Have you tried my fiddle and the website you are working on?

Comment: It looks it's working now in Chrome as well. Maybe some caching issue I'm not sure, weird. Thanks a lot for the explanation regarding the value attribute anyway!

Answer (score 0):

it's works! Its updating input's value, but in chrome devtools it not shows this updates. Try submit this form and check network, then you will see that all data have been sent correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**onSelect**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event of datetimePicker plugin.

```
 $('#deliveryTime').datetimepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         $('#'+inst.id).attr('value',dateText);
    }
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5rkbnrt/11/)